# Grab a string starting with a certain sub-string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

I want to grab the cpu model of an android device using

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

The output is something like this

```
Processor   : AArch64 Processor rev 3 (aarch64)
processor   : 0
processor   : 1
processor   : 2
processor   : 3
processor   : 4
processor   : 5
Features    : fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 8
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 3

Hardware    : Qualcomm Technologies, Inc msm8992
Revision    : 000b
```

Now what I need is only the "msm8992". The last 4 numbers change from devices to another, So what I was thinking is to search for word that starts with "msm" and extract it but I am struggling with grep / awk commands.

Comment: Please show the relevant code. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps search for "Hardware" and extract the last word

```
$ awk '/^Hardware/{print $NF}' /proc/cpuinfo
```

`grep -oE 'msm[0-9]+'` might do as well.

Answer (score -1):

since you tag awk, I used awk for It. Please check it out

```
grep msm /proc/cpuinfo | awk '{print substr($0, length($0)-6,7)}'
```